# Running multiple instances of Identity server in docker cluster

Tags: docker, .net-core, identityserver4

I have a .net core 2.0 application basically Identity server 4.   This runs just fine when I have only one instance. However if I try to run more then one instance of the identity server I start having issues.

**First issue**

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>       CryptographicException: The key {ec55dd66-7caf-4423-9dd6-74768e80675d} was not found in the key ring.
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.UnprotectCore(Byte[] protectedData, bool allowOperationsOnRevokedKeys, out UnprotectStatus status)
>
> InvalidOperationException: The antiforgery token could not be decrypted.
>       Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.Internal.DefaultAntiforgeryTokenSerializer.Deserialize(string serializedToken)

I was able to work out that this is because the key was being generated on all the instances of the identity server rather than just one key generated and they all used that.

I added the following code.

```
services.AddDataProtection()
            .PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo(settingsSetup.Settings.PersistKeysDirectory))
            .SetDefaultKeyLifetime(TimeSpan.FromDays(90))
            .SetApplicationName($"Awesome-IdentityServer-{_env.EnvironmentName}");
```

Which basically tell the identity servers where to store the key.  I followed the instructions found here [Persisting keys when hosting in a Docker container](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/configuration/overview?tabs=aspnetcore2x#persisting-keys-when-hosting-in-a-docker-container) so I have `A folder that's a Docker volume that persists beyond the container's lifetime, such as a shared volume or a host-mounted volume.`

Unforutnatlly this hasnt worked either i am now getting the following error

> "idsrv was not authenticated. Failure message: Unprotect ticket failed"

Which i believe means that the keys need to be encrypted somehow.

What is  `Unprotect ticket failed` and how do I solve it?  Can i run multiple instances of Identity server in docker nodes?

**Now with encryption.**

```
services.AddDataProtection()
            .PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo(settingsSetup.Settings.PersistKeysDirectory))
            .SetDefaultKeyLifetime(TimeSpan.FromDays(90))
            .ProtectKeysWithCertificate(LoadCertificate())
            .SetApplicationName($"Awesome-IdentityServer-{_env.EnvironmentName}");
```

Identity server responds with the following error in the logs.

> No XML encryptor configured. Key {2e0f629c-9dca-44fa-922e-5c5613bd27c8} may be persisted to storage in unencrypted form.

The user is shown this error

> CryptographicException: Unable to retrieve the decryption key.
>   System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.EncryptedXml.GetDecryptionKey(EncryptedData encryptedData, string symmetricAlgorithmUri)

[Authentication with Docker in ASP.NET Core](http://innodroid.com/blog/post/auth-with-docker-aspnet-core) also mentions that this should be working.

I originally thought this was an issue with Identity Server 4 since their documentation stated that it is stateless.  I posted an issue over on GitHub [Stateless or not Stateless](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/2205) after going back and forth with them I am inclined to think this is more of a docker issue then an Identity server issue.

Comment: It feels like you're having to jump through a lot of hoops to achieve this. We run a load balanced setup with several servers and we use a shared database to store the keys by implementing the IXmlRepository interface and it works fine. A shared DB makes much more sense if you want to scale out too.

Comment: That was going to be my next step.   Its only one key file so to me it made sense to just have it in the directory having in in the db seams over kill but i may not have a choice.    *(I didn't mention it but we also have a load balance set up that part of this circus is not my job luckily)*

Comment: I found this  look about right?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/extensibility/key-management?tabs=aspnetcore2x

Comment: That looks like the right documentation to be getting on with yes :)

Comment: BTW, the keys do not have to be encrypted to work. You're fine to debug without encryption first :)

Comment: It works fine locally the problem is when i try and run it in docker there it says it must be encrypted.

Answer (score 4):

The usual issue I've seen with clients is that they've put their `AddDataProtection` registration before `AddIdentityServer`.

`AddIdentityServer` also calls `AddDataProtection` with the default settings, which unfortunately will override whatever registrations you previously made.

So short answer: you need to put `AddDataProtection` after `AddIdentityServer` in your `ConfigureServices` method.

Comment: I will give it a try tomorrow and get back to you.  Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 1):

I struggeled with this for days trying to implement a shared docker volume but it didn't work even when encrypting the keys witha certificate. So I ended up using the database -as suggested by **@mackie**.

Here is some code for inspiration:

```
 X509Certificate2  cert = X509CertificateHelper.GetCertificateFromFile(options.Certificate.FilePath, options.Certificate.Passphrase);
 builder.AddSingleton<IXmlRepository, MongoXmlRepository>();
 var sp = builder.BuildServiceProvider();
 builder.AddSingleton<IXmlRepository, MongoXmlRepository>();
 builder.AddDataProtection()
        .SetApplicationName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName)
        .AddKeyManagementOptions(o =>
                {
                    o.XmlRepository = sp.GetService<IXmlRepository>();
                })
        .ProtectKeysWithCertificate(cert)
        .SetDefaultKeyLifetime(TimeSpan.FromDays(options.LifeTimeInDays));
```

**MongoXmlRepository** is just a class implementing the **IXmlRepository** interface:

```
/// <summary>
/// Implementation of the IXmlRepository, used by the DataProtection Service
/// </summary>
public class MongoXmlRepository : CrudRepository<MongoXElement, string>, IXmlRepository
{
    public MongoXmlRepository(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory,
        DatabaseRegistry databaseRegistry)
        : base(loggerFactory, databaseRegistry)
    {

    }
    public IReadOnlyCollection<XElement> GetAllElements()
    {
        try
        {
            var asyncCursor = this.Collection
                .Find(Builders<MongoXElement>.Filter.Empty);
            var entities = asyncCursor.ToList();
            var xml = entities.Select(e => XElement.Parse(e.Xml)).ToList();
            return xml;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            var errMessage = $"MongoXmlRepositoryError on {this.GetType()}:GetAllElements()";
            this.Logger.LogError(errMessage, e);
            throw new RepositoryException(errMessage, e);
        }
    }

    public async void StoreElement(XElement element, string friendlyName)
    {
        var key = new MongoXElement
        {
            Xml = element.ToString(SaveOptions.DisableFormatting)
        };
        await this.InsertAsync(key);


    }
}
```

The implementation may differ depending on your store, in this case MongoDb was used.